# Dynamically iterate through a JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have this JSON string:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Oct 13, 2019 11:42:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2019-10-13T11:42:00+00:00",
    "updateduk": "Oct 13, 2019 at 12:42 BST"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "chartName": "Bitcoin",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "symbol": "&#36;",
      "rate": "8,392.9583",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 8392.9583
    },
    "GBP": {
      "code": "GBP",
      "symbol": "&pound;",
      "rate": "6,634.7343",
      "description": "British Pound Sterling",
      "rate_float": 6634.7343
    },
    "EUR": {
      "code": "EUR",
      "symbol": "&euro;",
      "rate": "7,605.7660",
      "description": "Euro",
      "rate_float": 7605.766
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```cs
var bpi = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)["bpi"];

foreach (var currency in bpi)
{
   // Do something with currency["rate"] for example
}
```

The problem is that `currency` represents the JSON object but not its content. How can I do that?

I searched around the web and couldn't find anything, I also tried casting `currency` to `JObject` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I'd suggest https://app.quicktype.io?share=VjJUujw2twmGEiFf2RRd as a starting point. 99% of JSON issues go away if you convert the JSON to a concrete type and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are having is that the members of `bpi` are `JProperty` instances - they have a name, and a value. The *value* of the property is the object with the data you are interested in, not the [property itself](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JProperty.htm).

In the place of your comment

`// Do something with currency["rate"] for example`

instead do something like

`Console.WriteLine(currency.Value["rate"]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JArray` and `JObject` classes from Newtonsoft.Json to achieve this.

Not 100% matching, but shows how to achieve samples are here: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ToObjectComplex.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the `Value` property of the returned object.

```
foreach (var bpis in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(j)["bpi"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(bpis.Value["rate"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(bpis.Value["code"].Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

(...)

JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);

var bpis = o["bpi"];
foreach( var bpi in bpis ) {
  Console.WriteLine(bpi);
}
```

Output:

```
"USD": {
  "code": "USD",
  "symbol": "&#36;",
  "rate": "8,392.9583",
  "description": "United States Dollar",
  "rate_float": 8392.9583
}
"GBP": {
  "code": "GBP",
  "symbol": "&pound;",
  "rate": "6,634.7343",
  "description": "British Pound Sterling",
  "rate_float": 6634.7343
}
"EUR": {
  "code": "EUR",
  "symbol": "&euro;",
  "rate": "7,605.7660",
  "description": "Euro",
  "rate_float": 7605.766
}
```

More examples at https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm